# How to dynamically create an HTML Table?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How can I dynamically create an HTML table or ASP table? I've tried with code below but it's not working.

```
Table tb = new Table();
tb.ID="tbl"+TBname;
TableRow rowNew = new TableRow();
tb.Controls.Add(rowNew);
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
{
    TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();
    Label lblNew = new Label();
    rowNew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
}
```

I want to create more then one HTML table using loop. How can I do this?

Comment: "It's not working." *What* is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: Are you adding the table to the page? Perhaps you're missing a `Controls.Add(tb)`?

Comment: Just wrap your example code in a for loop, if you want more than one HTML table.

Comment: hello -diiN it's not working means the above above code is not working..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hay -Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ...its working with your hint..thnq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use literal control say

In Design page:

```
     <asp:Literal id="ltrlctrl1" runat=server />
```

In Code behind:

```
     ltrlctrl1.Text = "<table><tr><td>your HTML table contents</td></tr></table>";
```

Refer to: [How to: Add Literal Web Server Controls to a Web Forms Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f93yf0ee(v=vs.85).aspx) for its dis/advantages.

Answer (score 0):

try this one if you want to create N no. of rows in dynamic HTML table

**Front end page**

```
<asp:Literal id="container" runat=server />
```

**Code behind**

```
string Tablecontent='';
int rowCount=10 //change value as per your need
for(int i=1;i<=rowCount;i++){
Tablecontent+="<tr><td>your HTML table contents</td></tr>";
}

container.Text="<table>"+Tablecontent+"</table>";
```

Comment: Your answer is about creating rows. OP is asking how to create multiple HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments above (that you say helped you solve the problem), you are not adding the `Table` object to the page. Add the following to your code:

```
Controls.Add(tb);
```

To create more than one HTML table, just wrap your example code in a for loop, like so:

```
int tableCount = 2; // Or however many tables you want.
for (int tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < tableCount; tableIndex++)
{
    Table tb = new Table();
    tb.ID = "tbl" + TBname;
    TableRow rowNew = new TableRow();
    tb.Controls.Add(rowNew);
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();
        Label lblNew = new Label();
        rowNew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid trying to create HTML code in C#, either by strings (BAD), or using the ASP.NET Table control (BAD Microsoft)

A much better solution is to type the HTML into the .aspx file and then drop values into it as needed. plus a <% foreach(...) { %> tag to make the rows repeat and you should be good to go.

your code will be far cleaner and nicer to maintain.

Comment: Never use the "<asp:Literal id="container" runat=server />" this tag is server side processing simply to render text. what a waste of server resources, just type in the HTML into the ASPX file instead.