# Populating a <asp:literal> with text from backend code

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to populate a  .net component with text from the backend .aspx file. However, when I test my web app most of the elements within the table are missing.

Prior to trying to run the code as a long string from the backend in the .aspx file, I ran it from the .aspx.cs file as HTML code to check the output was as expected, it was.

my literal component on the front-end

```
<asp:Literal ID="DashboardContainer" runat="server">
                    <%-- dashboard stuff --%>
                </asp:Literal>
```

code to populate literal component from the backend

```
String TableContents="";
foreach(....){
TableContents += " <table style='width: 100%; border-color:lightgray; border-style:solid; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-right:none; border-width:0.5px;'> "
                    + "<tr>" +

                        " <td style='width: 25%;'> " +
                           " <table style='width:95%;'> " +
                                "<tr>" +
                                   " <td>" +
                                       " <asp:ImageButton ID='ImageButton1' runat='server' CssClass='ImageBtn' ImageUrl='Images/TrackingImg.PNG' /> " +
                                   " </td>" +
                               " </tr> " +
                               " <tr>"+
                                   " <td>"+
                                       " <asp:Label ID='DashboardID' runat='server'></asp:Label>"+
                                    "</td>"+
                               " </tr>"+
                           " </table>"+
                        "</td>"+

                    "    <td style='width: 30%;'>"+
                           " <table style='width:95%;'>"+
                              "  <tr>"+
                                  "  <td>"+
                                      "  <asp:Label ID='Label6' runat='server' CssClass='DashboardLabel' Text='Project Title:'></asp:Label>"+
                                  "  </td>"+
                               " </tr>"+
                               " <tr>"+
                                  "  <td>"+
                                       " <asp:Label ID='ProjectTitleTxt' runat='server'></asp:Label>"+
                                    "</td>"+
                               " </tr>"+
                               " <tr>"+
                                    "<td>"+
                                        "<asp:Label ID='Label7' runat='server' CssClass='DashboardLabel' Text='Created By:'></asp:Label>"+
                                   " </td>"+
                               " </tr>"+
                              "  <tr>"+
                                   " <td>"+
                                 "       <asp:Label ID='CreatedByTxt' runat='server'></asp:Label>"+
                                    "</td>"+
                               " </tr>"+
                               " <tr>"+
                                  "  <td>"+
                                      " <asp:Label ID='Label9' runat='server' CssClass='DashboardLabel' Text='Date Created:'></asp:Label>"+
                                   " </td>"+
                              "  </tr>"+
                               " <tr>"+
                                  "  <td>"+
                                      "  <asp:Label ID='DateTxt' runat='server'></asp:Label>"+
                                   " </td>"+
                               " </tr>"+
                           " </table>"+
                       " </td>"+

                      "  <td style='width: 35%'>"+
                            "<table style=' width:95%;'>"+
                               " <tr>"+
                                   " <td>"+
                                          " <asp:Label ID='Label8' runat='server' CssClass='DashboardLabel' Text='Project Description:'></asp:Label>"+
                                   " </td>"+
                             "   </tr>"+
                              "  <tr>"+
                                  "  <td style=' width:95%;  height:120px;'>"+
                                     "   <asp:Label ID='DescriptionTxt' runat='server'></asp:Label>"+
                                 "   </td>"+
                              "  </tr>"+
                         "   </table>"+
                        "</td>"+
                  "  </tr>"+
                "</table>";
            }
            DashboardContainer.Text = TableContents;
```

The actual result is just a table with the border and nothing within. The expected result should contain 3 separate tables each with labels and text.

I'm not sure what the problem is. I followed what I'd read here -  [How to dynamically create an HTML Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891828/how-to-dynamically-create-an-html-table)

Comment: Creating giant HTML strings in your code behind is a **bad** idea. I would recommend the 2nd answer approach to the SO post you linked. You are probably having issue with the server side controls (i.e. `<asp:Label />`, `<asp:ImageButton />`) not rendering. ASP server control just render out HTML anyways, so maybe try removing all the `<asp:Label>` and replacing them with actual HTML... like `<label>`'s

Comment: @zgood, Thanks for your comment. I'll give the second option a try by leaving the html code in the aspx.cs file and populating the required fields from the backend. However, I need replicate the code multiple times depending on the number of rows in my database. How can I duplicate the HTML code from the front-end to accommodate this? cheers

Comment: If I was doing this I would use a `<asp:ListView />` which would have you HTML table markup in it for the `<LayoutTemplate>` and `<ItemTemplate>` then just bind you data to that ListView. Then all HTML is managed in the ListView. Another option is to replace your `<asp:Literal>` with something like a `<asp:Panel>`, then loop through your data set (rows) creating [HtmlTable's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable?view=netframework-4.7.2), Rows and Cell's then adding them to the Panel's control collection (i.e. `Panel.Controls.Add(HtmlTable)`)

Comment: @zgood thanks again. Could you direct me to an article or video on how to do either of these implementations? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using something like an `<asp:ListView />` to accomplish something like this. It's easier to manage the HTML on the aspx page rather than a string in the .cs code-behind.

A simple implementation of this would look like this:

ASPX Page

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvProjects" ItemType="Domain.Models.Project">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="width: 100%; border-color:lightgray; border-style:solid; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-right:none; border-width:0.5px;"> 
                <tr> 

                    <td style="width: 25%;">  
                    <table style="width:95%;">  
                        <tr> 
                            <td> 
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CssClass="ImageBtn" ImageUrl="Images/TrackingImg.PNG" />  
                            </td> 
                        </tr>  
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="DashboardID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td style="width: 30%;">
                    <table style="width:95%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" CssClass="DashboardLabel" Text="Project Title:"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="ProjectTitleTxt" runat="server" Text="<%#Item.ProjectTitle%>"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" CssClass="DashboardLabel" Text="Created By:"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="CreatedByTxt" runat="server" Text="<%#Item.CreatedBy%>"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" CssClass="DashboardLabel" Text="Date Created:"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="DateTxt" runat="server" Text="<%#Item.DateCreated%>"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td style="width: 35%">
                    <table style=" width:95%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" CssClass="DashboardLabel" Text="Project Description:"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style=" width:95%;  height:120px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionTxt" runat="server" Text="<%#Item.Description%>"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            lvProjects.DataSource = ProjectService.GetAll();
            lvProjects.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Now the ListView will render out that HTML in the `<ItemTemplate>` for each row in your data set.

And of course I don't know what your objects are (here I just made up the `Domain.Models.Project` object and set it to the ItemType of the listview... yours will be different) or what your service call looks like to get you data in the Page_Load.

Comment: That's great, thanks for your help. +1 I also found this improved my understanding - https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-ASPNet-ListView-from-database-and-Repeat-columns-horizontally-using-GroupTemplate.aspx

Comment: np... also if you don't have a list of objects (`Domain.Models.Project` in the example) like I used and its like a DataTable or some type of anonymous object, instead of the `<%#Item.ProjectTitle%>` (because you won't have an `ItemType` defined) you can use the Eval statement ... `<%# Eval("ProjectTitle") %>`